# EventListener doesn't see 'click' event on ''thead' element of table

Tags: javascript, html-table, addeventlistener

I have predefined such table in HTML:

```
<div id="products">
    <table>
          <thead id="tableHeader">
          </thead>

          <tbody>
          </tbody>
    </table>
</div><!-- END of products-->
```

I fullfill whole table (thead and tbody) dynamically with JS.

The problem is, i wanted to add EventListener to each **`<`th`>`** element of table, so when i click on it - something should happen. However, my code doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('tableHeader').childNodes[0].addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    var t = e.target;
    console.log(t);
    if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'th')
    {
        console.log(t);
    }
}, false);
```

But when i **console.log(document.getElementById('tableHeader').childNodes[0]);** - it shows me correctly first **th** element, so (as you can see on screen) it's **`<th>`PRODUCENT`</th>`**. Why then EventListener doesn't catch anything?

Whole table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcRkz.jpg
[image]

Comment: How are you populating the table? Are you adding the eventListener *after* you have populated it?

Comment: Yes, i am adding EventListener after i create table. Creating table is other function with it's own loops.

Comment: The generated markup looks strange...

Comment: `document.getElementById('tableHeader').childNodes[0]` will return a `text` node

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, your table html code is so weird.

th tag - 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

HTML

```
<div id="products">
<table>
      <thead id="tableHeader">
           <tr>
               <th>
                   PRODUCTS
              </th>
          </tr>                      
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      </tbody>
</table>
</div><!-- END of products-->
```

Javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById('tableHeader').childNodes[1].addEventListener('click', 
    function(e) {      
       var t = e.target;        
       if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'th'){
           console.log(t);
     }
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, cause my way of creating table (but especially headers) is, as you called it, "weird". I create table with this (i assume too long and "bad") code: http://pastebin.com/GUUbfUam

Answer (score 0):

Get all the `th` element from `thead`first then add `addEventListener` to all those `th` using `forEach` loop. Try the following:

```js
var th = document.querySelectorAll('#tableHeader th')
th.forEach(function(thEl){
  thEl.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var t = e.currentTarget;        
    console.log(t);
    //or simply use this
    //console.log(this);
  });
});
```

```css
thead th{
  cursor: pointer;
}
thead th:nth-child(odd){
  background: #b4bac4;
}
thead th:nth-child(even){
  background: #efdf94;
}
```

```html
<div id="products">
  <table>
    <thead id="tableHeader">
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```